# Change hostname for windows server 2012 R2 data center

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012, azure

Currently we are having 3 production domain servers in azure with BizSpark subscription

```
1. Windows Server 2012 R2 datacenter - AD, DNS server (Server-03)
2. Windows Server 2012 R2 essentional server (Server-06)
3. Windows Server 2012 R2 datacenter - File server (server-10)
```

Now we have decided to move for Pay-as-go  subscription. 
since all the server in azure while recreating the servers with latest image in new subscription we have decided to change its hostname orderly as
1.Server-01,  2.Server-02,  3.Server-03

Currently 50 client computer is connected to this domain

How we have to prepare for changing the host name?

What process need to be done at server and client computer side?

Please kindly share your best suggestions

Thanks,
Nihal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there isn't anything special about a Domain Controller in Azure, you can simply rename the servers. They'll update their corresponding A records (and optionally PTR records) in the AD DNS zone.

You shouldn't need to do anything on the client machines, but if you'd like you can either flush their DNS cache or reboot them after the server rename to make sure they resolve the new server names correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, what if I change the azure virtual network IP range (10.0.10.0/24). I could able to login servers with newly assigned IP?